# Lost all submitted tasks in ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I have a thread pool instantiated with

```
    LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> taskQue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>();
    new ThreadPoolExecutor(100, 100, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, taskQue );
```

I submitted a large number (18k+) of Runnable tasks to it; each task will process and send data to another LinkedBlockingQueue, say dataQue, and I have a while(True) loop to poll and process those data from dataQue.

I am logging the size of taskQue every minute, it works fine for a while because I can see its size decreases gradually. However, after about 20 mins since the program starts, the size drops from 17927 to 0! My program is still running at this point and the while loop is still processing data from dataQue.

I am wondering how this is possible? I have been googling around and reading the javadocs. Neither LinkedBlockingQueue nor ThreadPoolExecutor seems to cancel/timeout tasks automatically. Is it possible that GC eats my tasks?

Comment: yeah, its class variable so shouldnt go out of scope. I checjed all of its threads are alive just waiting for tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No that's not possible. It's most certainly due to something in your code.

A very common scenario is that your tasks are failing due to some exception (and hence very quickly), but you just don't see the stack trace. One easy thing is to catch `Throwable` in your task and log the exception. You can also use a `Callable` instead and check the tasks' status via the returned `Future`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think you are right. Let me add sone logs to verify.

Comment: Thanks again! This is indeed the problem.